# Ordering advertisements/offers to increase revenue (confidence algorithm?)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, ads

I have a site where there will be a list of offers that the user can fill out for virtual currency. What's a decent algorithm to decide what order to arrange them by?

What's important:

- New offers move up so more people see them in order to get some
  metrics on them
- Highest EPC offers are on top (best money makers, highest converting)

The metrics I have:

```
 - Tags (if the user likes movies, the offers tagged with movies should move up)
 - Reported EPC - EPC of the offer according to the affiliate network
 - Network EPC  - EPC of the offer across all of our sites
 - Site EPC     - EPC of the offer on this site
 - Source EPC   - EPC of the offer from a certain source (there can be multiple per user)
 - Payout       - How much the offer pays per conversion (lead)
 - Clicks       - Clicks network-wide, site-wide, and from a certain source
```

Is there any recommended algorithm for this kind of problem? I was thinking some sort confidence algorithm (like the Wilson sorting algorithm) but I haven't a clue how to implement that with the metrics I have. Any ideas?

Comment: I heard yahoo fired 2000 people yesterday. You should hire some of them. Solving this problem would require at least 50 of them!

Comment: ^ yeah I understand it's a complicated problem, but isn't there any basic algorithm I can build from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically trying to build a ad recommender system. This should be a good starting point: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/icml11-tutorial/ . Take a look at the netflix challenge (movie recommender), KDD cup 2011 challenge (Music recommender) etc